# Limit the orbit movement in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm having trouble to set rotational limits to the viewer.
I want my viewer to work like this example in Three.js
https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_orbit
Is there anyone that has succeeded with this? And can give me some hints to lead me in the right direction..

I've tried using the code in the example above.
I've tried to set viewer.autocam.constrainOrbitVertical = true when reaching my limit that is about 90 degrees, but it wont give me the result I want..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately such a functionality is not available in Forge Viewer. You should however be able to work around it by controlling the camera properties on each `CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT`, for example like so:

```
    viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT, function() {
        const camera = viewer.getCamera();
        if (camera.position.x > 0) {
            const dist = camera.position.length();
            camera.position.x = 0;
            camera.position.setLength(dist);
            viewer.navigation.updateCamera();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested. As I can see it it stops where it should and that is good... But it starts a "chain reaction" and zooming in on my model and turns it around. Do you have any idea how to stop that and just stay in the same camera position and keep camera.position.x = 0?

Comment: Yeah, that's probably because simply nulling the x coordinate makes the distance from the target shorter with every little orbit movement. You'll probably need to measure the distance from target _before_ making the adjustment, and then, when you need to set the x coord to zero, reapply the scale factor to make sure that the distance is the same.

Comment: I've updated the code snippet to keep the distance from _origin_ constant.

Comment: You are soo close to solve this for me.. :-). But now it stops zooming and the only thing left is that it turns to a very random position and it does it directly when I reach x=0. Do you have any idea how to solve that problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "turns to a very random position"? I've tested the code snippet locally and don't see any weird behavior anymore.

Comment: The effect I get is this.. When I rotate it to X=0 it immediately rotates the model for example 540 degrees around x-axis and 350 degrees around z-axis.. The rotations is completly random every time. Where did you place your code? Maybe my problem  is that I placed it in "function onItemLoadSuccess(viewer, item)"

Comment: Not sure if the placement of the code would have this effect, but I placed it in `load` method of one of my extensions.

Comment: Your code works perfect if I test it on another computer.. So the strange behavior of my model rotating after setting x=0 is something in my computer. I don't know what but that is something I try to solve by myself. Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry.. Not perfect. :-). One last thing happen. It works nice if the model I use is very zoomed in. But if I zoom and make the model smaller on screen it starts to pan while I'm moving my mouse upwards when X=0. Do you get the same behavoir?